# Simple Caesar Cipher Program in C

Tags: c, encryption, caesar-cipher

Hey guys I'm starting to learn C, and I was asked to code a program specifically, a caesar cipher (so, the idea is to replace any letter in the message by a letter three positions down the alphabet.)

My implementation should read a line of text and then either performs encryption or decryption, depending on the first character read. If the first character is $, then I'm supposed to encrypt the rest of the line, and precede the output by the character ?. If the first character is ?, then I'm supposed to decrypt the rest of the line, and precede my output by the character $.

So for example: ?Wr eh, ru qrw wr eh

the output should be: $To be, or not to be

and vice versa.

So this is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char code[100], ch;
    int i;

    scanf("%s", &code);

    if(code[0]  == '$'){
        for(i = 0; code[i] != '\0'; ++i){
            ch = code[i];

            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                ch = ch + 3;

                if(ch > 'z'){
                    ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
                }

                code[i] = ch;
            }
            else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                ch = ch + 3;

                if(ch > 'Z'){
                    ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
                }

                code[i] = ch;
            }
        }
        printf("?%s\n", code);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But the problem is, it returns the first character and stops whenever there are space.
Like for example I enter: $To be it outputs to: ?$To

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `fgets` instead of `scanf`.

Comment: note : `%s` of `scanf` doesn't include whitespaces.

Comment: ...because `scanf("%s", &code);` (which in any case should be `scanf("%s", code);`) stops at the first whitespace character.

Comment: I suggest reading and processing the input one character at a time (e.g. with `getchar()`), instead of first reading it all into a string.  Not only will that allow you to overcome your current problem, but it will also handle arbitrarily long lines, and even (with some caveats) multiline inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample using [`getchar()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) to get you started:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ch; // Either EOF or one of the chars in 0-255
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') {
            int offset = ch - 'A';
            printf("%c", 'a' + offset);
        } else {
            printf("%c", ch);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this code isn't perfect in a lot of ways, but it does demonstrate how to use `getchar()`. Every time `getchar()` is called, it fetches the next `char` from standard input and returns it as an `int`. That's because when the input is over, it returns the special value `EOF`, which is outside the range of `char`.

The while loop here is a common idiom. When execution reaches the loop, it first has to call `getchar()`, whose result is stored into  `ch`. Then it checks whether `ch` is `EOF`. If not, then the loop processes the character that was read. Otherwise, it exits and the program ends.

The body of the loop prints every character it sees, while converting the uppercase letters to lowercase.

Comment: Note that `char ch = (char) i;` is unnecessary. `'A'` is of type `int` and you can work with `int` throughout, even pass `int` for the format specifier `%c`, because a `char` type is promoted to `int` anyway.

Comment: ^ Right. I wanted to make it abundantly clear that `getchar()` returns something in the range of `char` unless it's EOF.

Comment: `getchar` returns `int`, which might be out of the range of `char` if `char` is signed.